# How do I get the battery indicator to indicate total remaining power if I have 2 batteries?

Tags: 11.10, battery, indicator

I'm having a little bit of trouble with my battery indicator. I'm using a laptop that has 2 batteries (One standard and one bay battery). They are both recognized and used fine by Ubuntu, however I have one problem.

The indicator shows both batteries, but only ever gives me info for the main battery. For instance, the entire time I am draining the bay battery, my indicator shows (100%) because it is only telling me about the main battery. If I go to power settings, I can see a combined time:

[image]

Is there any way in 11.10 to have the indicator show me the total estimated remaining time?

Also, if the bay battery runs out and starts using the main battery and then I put the laptop into suspend, when it comes out of suspend, it will give me a low battery warning and then re-suspend itself. This can be alleviated by restarting, but is quite annoying. Any ideas for this?

Thanks for any help you all might have!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://live.gnome.org/Design/SystemSettings/Power there should be (in the near future) a display for secondary devices, which should be able to reflect your secondary batteries state. However at the time being this does not work for me in precise either.